# Apache sites do not have http:// prefix in address bar

Tags: apache, url, lamp

I've setup 4 sites on a LAMP stack and pointed a number of domains at the server. Everything is running nicely but for some reason, none of the sites have the http:// prefix.

It isn't a massive problem but down-the-line, these sites are going to run https on secure areas and I want visitors to be able to differentiate.

Why would Apache NOT display the http:// prefix? I'm using named virtual hosts and have modified my /etc/hosts file to point the relevant domains to my server's IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely the *browser* hiding the `http://` prefix. It should be happening on every other web site you visit with that browser, too.

[image]

You can't control this with Apache - but don't worry, in https mode, the browser will make sure the user sees the difference.

Comment: This was exactly right. If you copy and paste from the address bar the http:// is added.